# How to export Data into .csv file in linq c# via button click

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, linq, dbcontext

i'm traying in a simple way to export the data of table (scores) from the database into .csv file.
I want to do that via a button click. I use WPF and save data tabel in SQLite
Note: The table is not displayed in the DataGridView
scores table has columns: PersonId, PersonName, ScoreDate

```
 private void ExportToCSV(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\MAFA\Desktop\newfolder\endscores.csv"))
        {
            // how can i here call the table from the database ?! 

        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your SQLite Note data structure, whether it's a list or not, but usually something like this works for me:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\MAFA\Desktop\newfolder\endscores.csv"))
{
    yourSQLiteNoteDataStruct
        .Select(i => $"{i.PersonId};{i.PersonName};{i.ScoreDate};")
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(s => sw.WriteLine(s));
}
```

This will of course lock your UI and make it unresponsive for the time being while the file is written. Therefore you can make your event handler `async` and the stream writer part wrapped in task:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    ...
});
```

Comment: thank you, actually it's a list but i didn't understand your answer. Can you explain more please? or do you have another answer solution?

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand? Have you already tried the first part? Does it save an CSV with the content you require? And what happens to your UI then?